# How does an electronic shocker works?

Tags: transistors, transformer, spark, shock

I'm new to electronics but I want to make this diagram from ["Instructables"](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-build-the-Worlds-Smallest-Electronic-Shock/step4/The-beginning-of-the-hardest-part-ever/) :

[image: Electronic shocker]

I have everything I need from a camera... I also realized, using a different transformer, that the sparks are made only when the battery is deconnected and reconected repeatedly, like in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxAz0_yOrS4&feature=youtu.be&t=2m11s). So ,I was wandering if that transistor is acting something like an oscillator (closing and reopening the circuit).

Am I right or the transistor is used for something else? 
And if I'm right can you explain me how the transistors closes and reopens the connection?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my mistakes(this is not my original language...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the transistor works as an oscillator.

Let see if I can explain the working. The transistor starts by conducting, because it gets base current via de resistor and the small section of the secondary coil. For some time the current through the primary coid will increase. When its stops increasing, the sudden drop in the change of current is transformed to the (small) secondary coil and causes the transistor to switch off. This effect is only temporary, and when it is over the cycle starts again.